# get value from div and class

Tags: c#

How can I get value "3,2" and text "MB/s(KB/s)" every second from website using c#?

```
<div class="download speed-block">
  <i class="small-icon icons-sprite green-down-arrow">
  </i>
  <span class="dark-numbers">3,2</span>
  <span class="light-txt">МB/s</span>
</div>
```

And how I can get width value "19%" in int

```
<div class="download progress-block">
  <div class="download progress-bar" style="width: 19%;
  "></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @martin, is the question related to `c#`? You may review your question and remove the `c#` tag if it is not relevant. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do like this.

```js
var number = document.querySelector(".dark-numbers");
var text = document.querySelector(".light-txt");
var progress = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.progress-bar')).width);
var width = window.innerWidth

console.log(number.innerHTML,text.innerHTML);
console.log("persentage:", Math.ceil(progress/width*100),"%");
```

```css
.progress-bar{
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="download speed-block">
  <i class="small-icon icons-sprite green-down-arrow">
  </i>
  <span class="dark-numbers">3,2</span>
  <span class="light-txt">МB/s</span>
</div>

<div class="download progress-block">
  <div class="download progress-bar" style="width:19%">19%</div>
</div>
```